# Specific Row Coloring on DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, datagrid

I've been working all day on this issue:
I'm using DataGrid on an asp vb app and I'm trying to code it in a way it has on row of one color and one in another, I've tried looking into the DataGrid properties but there's no such thing as a row number or position I can work with.
its supposed to go like this

**blue**
*red*
**blue**
*red*
**blue**
*red*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in VB.NET. Check this out :

```
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If row.Index Mod 2 Then
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
        Else
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue
        End If
    Next
```

use the event **RowsAdded** of the **DataGridView**.

To prevent disarray after deleting specific row, you should add the code again in the event **RowsRemoved.**

Answer (score 0):

use Gridview and by its alternating item property you can have the desired result. set its item style and alternating item style for differant colours